# Attributes for image stored using Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am using the [NPM documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) for uploading an image to Google Cloud Storage

```
app.post('/test', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    });
    let bucket = gcs.bucket('bucket-name');

    bucket.upload(req.file.path, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
        console.log(file);
    });

    console.log(req.file);

    // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Is there any way I can specify a custom name and file type for the file I'm uploading? In my case it should be an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass options to your upload method:

```
var options = {
  destination: 'my-image-name.jpg',
  metadata: {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  }
};

bucket.upload(req.file.path, options, function(err, file) {
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any benefits over creating a writestream rather than using the upload method?

Comment: The `bucket.upload` is just a convenience method that will do `createWriteStream` [check documentation api](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/0.5.0/storage/file?method=createWriteStream)